# Difference between Mutlipole moments calculated with normal integration and with Wigner-$D$ matrices

Tags: electrostatics, representation-theory, multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics

Im learning about Wigner-$D$ matrices and the applications to spherical harmonics. Now I wanted to test my knowledge, but i failed miserably :( (worked on this the whole day). So here is my problem:

I want to calculate the (spherical) multipole moments of an point charge q sitting on the z-axis at a, but rotated about the angle $\beta$:
$$\rho'(r,\theta,\varphi) = \frac{q}{r^2 sin(\theta)} \, \delta(r-a) \, \delta(\theta-\beta) \, \delta(\varphi).$$

Calculating the multipole moments of this charge distribution yields:

$q'^{(1)}_{lm}=q \, a^l \, Y_{lm}^*(\beta,0)$

Now to the Wigner-D Matrices: In my book it says:

$Y_{lm}^*(\theta',\varphi') =   \sum_{m'=-l}^l D_{mm'}^{(l)}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \, Y_{lm'}^*(\theta,\varphi)$.

So my understanding is now, that you can insert the definition of the multipolemoments in this formula, rearange terms and then resubsitute the multipolemoments (see added photo), so you do get:

$q'^{(2)}_{lm}=   \sum_{m'=-l}^l D_{mm'}^{(l)}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \, q_{lm'}$.

and with the charge distribution from above:

$q'^{(2)}_{lm}=   \sum_{m'=-l}^l D_{mm'}^{(l)}(0,\beta,0) \, q_{lm'}$.

My problem is now: Some multipole moments (which are symmetric in $\beta$ are the same, but for example the multipole moments for l=1 and m=1 are the same, except for the sign?!

I am new to this topic, so i could made a error in my derivation of $q'^{(2)}_{lm}$ because of some lack of understanding of Wigner-D matrices or something else. I tested this also on another more complex charge distributions (model of a comet), but there are no differences between the normal integration $q_{lm}$ and computation with Wigner-D matrices, thats why it confuses me even more.

I appreciate any tips :), best regards

Stefan

[image]

Comment: Please enter your mathematics using MathJax. It is very important to the proper functioning of this site.

Comment: The sentence after "My problem is now:" seems to be missing some part (also the parentheses don't match). This makes answering the question difficult.